# initialize value in android viewmodels

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, viewmodel

I got an error when using init method in viewmodels and access it at the main activity.

Unresolved reference: loginStatus

I think it cannot access this value.

how can I solve this?

```
class LoginViewModel: ViewModel() {

    init {
        if (Firebase.auth.currentUser != null) {
            val loginStatus by mutableStateOf(true)

        } else {
            val loginStatus by mutableStateOf(false)
        }
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModelby viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (loginViewModel.loginStatus) {
            println("login true")
        }
    }
}
```

and I tried to solve this problem using lazy method, however, it didn't work. Is there any method?

```
val loginStatus : Boolean by lazy { mutableStateOf(true)}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you getting `Unresolved reference: loginStatus`? Besides that, if you want to handle Firebase authentication in clean architecture, you might be then interested in reading the following article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code outside the init block like this

```
val loginStatus by lazy {
      mutableStateOf(Firebase.auth.currentUser != null)    
  }

or 

 val loginStatus by lazy {
        if (Firebase.auth.currentUser != null) {
            mutableStateOf(true)

        } else {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't I use it with init block?

Comment: no, you can't access your variable of init block in different class